# Why doesn't the Delphi compiler throw a warning when a class method uses self?

Tags: delphi

At my workplace, we have some code where `class function`s refer to `Self`, effectively creating a potential access violation, should the object not be initialised.  Does the meaning of `Self` change in a class method as to refer the class rather than the object?

I assume the only reason this is working is because the `Self` refers to another `class function` and not a regular method.

I created the following test class:

```
constructor TTest.Create;
begin
  FTest := 'Hej';
end;

procedure TTest.GoTest;
begin
  ShowMessage(FTest);
end;

class procedure TTest.Test;
begin
  Self.GoTest;
end;
```

However, compiling this throws an error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(51): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor
```

I also testing referring to FTest directly, which gave another error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(51): E2124 Instance member 'FTest' inaccessible here
```

But I wonder, however, whether it is possible to have a case where `Self` is potentially dangerous in class methods.

I know, that referring to global objects and assume they are there is always bad.

Comment: Walk through the code, set a brekapoint and see what "self.name" is at that point. I don't like using self too much as it depends on context what self is.

Comment: Perhaps then, Delphi should hint that `Self` is potential to cause confusion.  Or would change meaning if the method is moved to a different class.

Comment: If the hint - it should be easily suppressible. I don't want hints every time i use Self

Comment: I doubt we can get Delphi to hint about non-idiomatic usage of Delphi.  Because there are scenarios - as the accepted answer describes - where `Self` in class methods have their purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the meaning of Self change in a class method as to refer the class rather than the object?

In a class method `Self` refers to the class. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Methods) says:

> In the defining declaration of a class method, the identifier Self represents the class where the method is called (which can be a descendant of the class in which it is defined.) If the method is called in the class C, then Self is of the type class of C. Thus you cannot use Self to access instance fields, instance properties, and normal (object) methods. You can use Self to call constructors and other class methods, or to access class properties and class fields.
>
> A class method can be called through a class reference or an object reference. When it is called through an object reference, the class of the object becomes the value of Self.

The compiler won't object to you using `Self` since it is a legal and supported thing to do. It just complains when you try to use instance members, instance methods etc.

`Self` has this meaning in class methods for exactly the same reason it exists in instance methods. It allows you to fully specify a symbol and thus avoid scoping ambiguity. What's more it allows you to access the actual class on which the method is called. This may be a descendant of the class in which the method is defined.

> I wonder, however, whether it is possible to have a case where `Self` is potentially dangerous in class methods.

I don't see any particular danger inherent in this part of the language. In fact the use of `Self` reduces scope and so reduces the danger of inadvertently referring to a local variable rather than a class member.

Comment: So using `Self` in class methods is idiomatic Delphi?

Comment: Not really. Normally you would omit it just as you do in instance methods. If you need to use it because you have a variable scoping collision then you probably need to consider renaming either the local variable of class member that collided.

Comment: Well, thanks, that's what I needed to know!  Fortunately, removing these instances of `Self` should be rather easy.

Comment: I would say it's idiomatic. In Java and C++ you cannot use `this` in class (static) methods.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera That's not what idiomatic means. You could say that in C++ it is idiomatic to put the constant on the left in a comparison expression (to guard against writing = when you meant ==), but in Delphi it would not be even though you could do that. In other words, idiomatic isn't about what is possible in a language, more about how things are expressed by the majority of programmers.